# Updating constraints in animation with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I want an animation to move a UIImageView to a new position defined by a new set of constraints, but for some reason I cannot get it to work. I'm trying to do:

```
@IBOutlet weak var oldBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

...

func animateMovement() {
     // Here I'm defining a new constraint
     var newBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: self.logo,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.usernameField,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 15)

     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        // Here I'm setting the already existing constraint (defined in storyboard) to the new constraint 
        self.oldBottom = newBottom
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        }, completion: {})
}
```

Comment: Don't call layoutIfNeeded outside of the animation block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the error at it was a very simple one. I did not callself.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false) since I thought that was already handled by the storyboard (since I use autolayout in it). I simply added that before updating the constraint. 
Thanks for all the inputs :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the constraints and animate the layoutIfNeeded, try this:

```
func animateMovement() {
     var newBottom = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: self.logo,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.usernameField,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 15)
     self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     self.oldBottom = newBottom
     UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
         self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
     }, completion: {})
```

Comment: I tried doing that, unfortunately it doesn't work :-/

Comment: is the constrains moving without animation?

Comment: No it wasn't but I found my mistake (see my update in the question) :-)